# PHP Order by Ascending/Descending not working

Tags: php, database

I'm designing a simple task list, but I encountered a little problem.
I want to be able to order the items from the database by clicking on a form button, but it is not working.

This is the code for ordering it between Ascending and Descending.

```
$type='ASC';
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    if ($type == 'DESC') {
         $type = 'ASC';  
    }
}elseif($type == 'ASC') {
    $type='DESC';  
}
```

The query for getting results from the DB:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id '. $type;
```

(EDIT: button is inside form tags with post method)
and the form button:

```
<form method="post"><button type="submit" name="sort" id="asc"></button></form>
```

This (in my opinion) should be able to work, but it doesn't.
anyone willing to help me find the problem?

Comment: how are you getting your `$type` variable?

Comment: That button won't actually send a $_POST variable called `asc` on its own. You'll need to put that in a form to post the information correctly. If it doesn't work can you echo the `$sql` query to see what you've actually sent to the database?

Comment: The button is inside form tags, forgot to put in in the question. The code I wrote has to do this: When the button is clicked, check if $type is DESC, if so, set $type to ASC, and vice versa. but it doesn't work. I've tried to declare the variable $type inside the function, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use form, you need to save the value to input type="hidden".

```
<?php
 $type = $_POST["sortvalue"];
 if(!$type) {
     $type = "ASC";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
     if ($type == 'DESC') {
         $type = "ASC";
     }elseif($type == 'ASC') {
         $type = "DESC";
     }
 }
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id '. $type;
?>

<form method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="sort" value="sort">Sort</button>
<input type="hidden" name="sortvalue" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
</FORM>
```

hope this work for you.. :D

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. I would like to ask you though, since I'm not very good at PHP. Why did you use a hidden input type? I don't understand how that works.

Comment: hidden input is just similar to another input, but hidden input is not shown on webpage, so if you want to pass data or temporary variable along with a form, you can use the hidden input, you can view how the hidden input works by using firebug. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$("body").on("click", "#asc", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 sort();
});

function sort() {
  var order = find("table#sort_order").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: order,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       // change sort order using data
    }, // End of success function of ajax form
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
      console.log("Status: " + status);
      console.dir(xhr);
    },
  }); // End of ajax call 
}
```